# Convert to proper dateTime format - dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a request coming as below format

```
{
   "updatedTime": "Mon Mar 14 15:34:47 NZDT 2022"
}
```

The response should be converted to  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

```
{
"updatedTime": "2022-03-14'T'15:34:47"
}
```

I also referred to Mule docs https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-cookbook-format-dates. Any thoughts? Thanks

Using Mule4, Dataweave 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the patterns characters in the documentation link you shared and construct the pattern for the whole date. You can also search for examples on the Java time package patterns, which are the ones in which DataWeave date/time patterns are based on.

The ones that perhaps are not obvious are to use patter `zz` for the timezone and `eee` for the localized day name.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    updatedTime: payload.updatedTime 
        as DateTime { format: "eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy" } 
        as LocalDateTime
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aled. That's was the thing which I didn't figure out, was using this pattern 'E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy' :). Great

Answer (score 2):

Another way of transforming the given input is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.updatedTime as DateTime {format: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"} 
as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of using an explicit pattern at the end but I believe you need a conversion from Local datetime to String so that last pattern is used.

Comment: @aled, i didnt get the menaing of "last pattern" here. could you please put a light on it.

Comment: I was partially wrong. I assumed that the last pattern was not used because the date time pattern is only used when converting to/from String and date/time types, not from date/time to date/time. However specifically for some output formats like JSON it appears that there is an implicit transformation to String, because there is no date/time type in JSON, and dates are represented as strings. So it works in your solution but it would not work in an XML output.

Comment: @aled yes correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach [Date-Parsing](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.1/dataweave-examples#conditional-date-parsing)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"updatedTime":(payload.updatedTime as String replace "NZDT" with "GMT")  as DateTime {format: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O yyyy"} as LocalDateTime
```

Output

```
{
  "updatedTime": "2022-03-14T15:34:47"
}
```

Comment: I advise to avoid string manipulations for date/times unless there is no alternative. In DataWeave there are ways to parse or transform the timezone so it is not really needed for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of `@aled` is correct I really like the [update operator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-values-functions-update) from Dataweave and than you can rewrite the Dataweave like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case .updatedTime -> $ as DateTime { format: "eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy" } as LocalDateTime
}
```

[image: Dataweave Playground]